# How to read a dynamic-sized excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I don't know if I expressed my question right, but I will tell you what I would like to know.

I have an excel file with multiple sheets. Each sheet has the same number of columns and different number of rows. I would like to read each excel sheet and store it in a 3D "item" (the first thing that came to mind is the equivalent form of a cell array of MATLAB). After I take this cell array, I want to be able to dynamically iterate through it.
For now I have written the following code in which I read the sheets in a 3D array (thus the excel sheets need to have the same dimensions):

```
excelF = pd.ExcelFile (fileName)
sheetsno = len(excelF.sheet_names)
dim = excelF.parse()
array = np.zeros((sheetsno,dim.shape[0],dim.shape[1]))
for i in range(0,sheetsno):
    df = pd.read_excel (fileName,sheet_name = i)
    array[i,:,:] = df.to_numpy()
```

Comment: Doesn't your code already achieve this? If you had a 3x2 array in sheet 1 and 3x3 in sheet 2 and 3x4 in sheet 3, do you want a 1d array that holds multiple 2D arrays, each with their own size( example: [ array(3x2), array(3x3), array(3x4) ], or do you want a 3d array that is 3x4?

Comment: I would want an 1D array that will hold the arrays (for your example  [ array(3x2), array(3x3), array(3x4) ]). I tried my code with different sizes and it was not working.

Comment: What do you mean the file is "dynamic-sized"? Also what is dynamically iteratation"?

Comment: Is my posted answer what you want? Or should I edit something?

Comment: Thank you very much @Zingerella for providing me a solution. For some reason however, your solution ignores the first line of the excel file? Do you know why?

Comment: pandas by default uses the first row as the "header" so basically the name of each column. To prevent this either give your excel sheets headers, or use `excelF.parse(i,header=None)` to  tell pandas not to skip the first row.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Zingerella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this code out and it worked on multiple sheets with multiple dimensions. I use a python list and append a np array to that list on every sheet. I don't think the next step is necessary (unless you want to work with numpy exclusively), but then I convert the list to a np.array

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
excelF = pd.ExcelFile ('test.xlsx')
array = []
for i in range(0,len(excelF.sheet_names)):
    df = excelF.parse(i) # use excelF.parse(i,header=None) to include first row    
    array.append(df.to_numpy())
array = np.array(array)
```